# Short GUID-128 with length of 16 base64 symbols?

Tags: base64, guid

Here is the online GUID generator which offer 16-symbols-long GUID: http://www.shortguid.com. They say that their Short GUID-128 is a `128-bit GUID represented as Base64 string. Short GUID Example: Z6y83ED2i0_mJ7i-`. I've tried to implement base64 encoding for GUID and the best result I got is 22 (same result listed in a great article http://blog.codinghorror.com/equipping-our-ascii-armor/). Does anybody have an idea how they(http://www.shortguid.com) generate such short GUID (I mean 16 base64 symbols is 12bytes and they are missing 4 byte of uniqueness of standart 16byte GUID :) )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation points to do so.

There was a bug in the code. It's fixed. Thanks for pointing it out. I will put a thank you note on the site, if you don't mind :)